# Programmatically mimic 2x mode (or double scale) of iPhone apps on iPads?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cordova, ios7

Our iPhone app, built with PhoneGap, is published as a Universal app. The Universal setting is required for app discovery on iPads and for the execution of certain PhoneGap plugins.

We tweaked a few height and width settings, but the scale is too small for some users.

We don't have the capacity to re-code the app and recreate assets for optimal rendering on iPads.

Instead, we would like to mimic the 2x mode available on iPads -- but only on iPads. 2x mode was available when the app was iPhone-only, but the option is obviously gone now that it's a Universal app.

Is there a way to invoke this functionality, either through HTML/CSS/JS or through Objective-C?

Thanks!

Comment: image are loaded in html or iOS?.

Comment: html. ideally we don't have to make any changes except for invoking code to put the app in "2x" mode -- just like the ipad button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fairly simple.. you can easily check if the device is iphone or pad

```
 var d = $('body').height():
 if(d > 548){

       $('body').css({'height':'548px','-webkit-transform': 'scale(2,2)'});

  }
```

the webkit transform scale actually scales every thing just like you want, and will make all your assets blurry etc but fonts divs etc in side the body scale =)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to scale up UI elements, and not the contents. For example, if you set `UIImageView` frame as `{ 0, 0, 100, 100 }`, then on iPad it'll still have frame as `{ 0, 0, 100, 100 }` and will look too small. What you want to do is to have separate XIB files for iPhone and iPad. In this way you'll be able to create `UIView` frames according to the platform.

At runtime iOS will choose appropriate XIB file for current platform. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW27) you'll be able to find some documentation about how it works.

Here you can see an example of that:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In you AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, do something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    ...

    // Get screen size
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGRect windowFrame = screenBounds;
    BOOL scale = NO;

    // Check if we are running on an iPad
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        // If this is the case, set the size to an iPhone with a 3.5 po screen, then scale
        windowFrame.size = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
        windowFrame.origin.x = (screenBounds.size.width - windowFrame.size.width) / 2.0;
        windowFrame.origin.y = (screenBounds.size.height - windowFrame.size.height) / 2.0;
        scale = YES;
    }

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:windowFrame];
    [self.window setClipsToBounds:YES];

    if (scale) {
        self.window.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0);
    }

    ... 

    return YES;
}
```

That way, you would mimic a 2X mode by setting the UIWindow to an iPhone screen size and applying a scale transform.  You would probably need to check for screen orientation, but I tried it with an iPhone only project changed into an universal app and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading images in html . You should set images in css and not in html directly using `@media` tags you need to write separate css for iPhone/iPad , iPhone/iPad retina .

http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/  . This link has all queries `@media` description

For example:

**Index.html**

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
   <div class="mynewDiv">
    ……………………………………

    ……………………………
    <div>
```

And in **style.css**

```
/* iPad STYLES GO HERE */

    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
    and (orientation : portrait)  {
        .mynewDiv
        {
          background: url("../image/iPadBg.png");
        }
    }
/* iPhone5 STYLES GO HERE */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) { 
       .mynewDiv
        {
          background: url("../image/iPhone5bg.png");
        }
}
/* iPhone STYLES GO HERE */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
       .mynewDiv
        {
          background: url("../image/iPhone5bg.png");
        }

 }
```

Like this you have to modify your html and css . Then appropriate images will loaded in devices

Comment: sorry as we mentioned in the question, we know this is possible by creating new image assets. we want to see if it's possible without new images. we understand the scaled-up images won't be as sharp, but that's okay. our goal is to mimic the 2x mode functionality.

Answer (score 0):

what ultimately worked was applying a special CSS class that defined `-webkit-transform: scale(2)` and `-webkit-transform-origin: top` while slicing the height and width by 50%. through javascript, we applied these modifications whenever any device exceeded a certain size, in our case 640 px.